# Javascriptless website built with React framework

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gatsby, tor, deep-web

I would like to port one of my websites, currently using python-flask and jinja2. Mainly because the DX of jinja2 is not great and because python is not typed by default whereas typescript is.

The issue is that this website needs to be usable from the deep-web (tor network), where it is better to not use Javascript since a lot of users have it disabled for security reasons.

From my research and personal experience, there are two candidates : Gatsby and NextJS. They can both generate pages without Javascript. But I wondered if there was not a dedicated framework to this intent.

I know this question is a bit stupid, "Javascript without Javascript huh?", but this is mainly because I am used to developing using React, and features like types, css modules and vast amount of front related libraries makes a so much better DX then simply Jinja2 templating.

thank you for reading and answering if you do so, I hope my question was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [jamstack websites](https://jamstack.org/). This being said, you can also use other languages as shown on the link.

NextJS and Gatsby are two options. There are also many Python-based ones, which should be comfortable to use as you already know Python.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will stick wit NextJS !